# Use javascript to change second select list based on first select list option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two drop-down lists populated from an array of same dates stored in a database. I want to use javascript or jquery to change the second drop-down list based on the selection from the first list. So an example would be if the user selects 03/03/2012 in the first, start date list, then I'd like the second list to only show or allow future dates within the array. 3/3, 3/2 and 3/1 would either be greyed out or removed and 3/4, 3/5 would remain as selectable options. Can anyone help with the javascript coding or make another recommendation?

```
<select id='start_date' name='data[sDate]' title='Use the drop list'>
<option value="" selected="selected"> </option>
<option value="03/05/2012">03/05/2012</option>
<option value="03/04/2012">03/04/2012</option>
<option value="03/03/2012">03/03/2012</option>
<option value="03/02/2012">03/02/2012</option>
<option value="03/01/2012">03/01/2012</option>
</select>

<select id='end_date' name='data[eDate]' title='Use the drop list'>
<option value="" selected="selected"> </option>
<option value="03/05/2012">03/05/2012</option>
<option value="03/04/2012">03/04/2012</option>
<option value="03/03/2012">03/03/2012</option>
<option value="03/02/2012">03/02/2012</option>
<option value="03/01/2012">03/01/2012</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Are you using server side language as well?

Comment: Good point, this would be a lot easier with something server side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your actual example, if the two lists are exactly the same then it's pretty simple if you work with `index()`. Look http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/7YrqY/

```
$('#start_date').change(function(){
    var $selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
    $('#end_date')
        .find('option')
        .prop('disabled', false)
        .eq($selected.index()-1)
        .nextAll()
        .prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Comment: +1 works great in jsfiddle and looks like it's what I need but my implementation is failing. Is there any additional component/resource I need to reference? I'm currently referencing ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few different solutions, including server side. This is a common scenario and I'm sure you could find more examples on this site if you searched a bit more.

http://css-tricks.com/dynamic-dropdowns/

Comment: That site is more about getting the second drop down list's element from various outside sources, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery

```
$(function(){ //when the page is loaded

$("#start_date").change(function(){ //register a anonymous function that will be called when the element with id=start_date changes his values

    var start = $(this).val(); //gets the value of the element

    $("#end_date option").each(function(i){//for each option of end_date

        if(new Date($(this).val()).getTime() < new Date(start).getTime()){ //if the date of the element is before the start
            $(this).hide(); //hide the element
        }else{
            $(this).show(); //shows the element
        }
    });

});
```

});

Ive not tested but is something like that